# Intellisense not working for python

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense and Snippets for Python are not working after installing python by donjayamanne's extension (ext install python) on vscode 1.8.1. Even pressing ctr+space, it just keeps "Loading..." and nothing happens.

I just just installed this new arch Linux with python-3.6 and new kernel's version. And once VSCode version 1.8.1 finished installing, I installed this extension, then Intellisense and Snippets for python stopped working, however they were working fine last week on the old version of Arch Linux.

I tried many things, I uninstalled both vscode and the extension many times, I changed the path as said [here](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Miscellaneous#select-an-interpreter) , and now I removed the current kernel (4.8) and installed 4.4-lts, yet nothing happened.

I thought of asking here before I go [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) to report an issue.

Comment: The problem was in python3.6. Once I installed python3.5 and changed the interpreter path inside vscode it worked.

Comment: See this link: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! The owner of the extension updated it and now it's good and working for python-3.6. Just install the new update.